# Define tables from a part of my ER Diagram

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship, relationship

I have a ER-Diagram (Show in http://www.4freeimagehost.com/show.php?i=f82997ca4d5d.png).
In the diagram you see 2 entities and a 1:N relataion together.
Project has 2 columns as ProjectID, ProjectName.
Employee has 3 colums as EmployeeID, EmployeeName and ProjectID.
A project has ONLY 1 project-manager and project-manager is a employee.
What columns add them?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to tag this 'homework'?

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution (EXACTLY ONE manager)

- Add the ManagerID into the Projects table

More generic solution (allows 0, 1 or more managers)

- Add a table "ManagesProject" with two columns: ProjectID, EmployeeID.

Comment: Are you sure for "Simple solution" option?It's very important.

Comment: It depends on your specifications. 'ONLY' one project-manager, is that 'EXACTLY ONE' or 'MAXIMUM ONE (zero allowed)'? The Generic Solution will work in all cases - when in doubt, use it, as it is more extensible.